# Grid and image overlapping Border?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, wpf, xaml

Hi I am trying to round the corners of an image or alternatively overlap my border ontop of the image but anything im trying doesnt seem to work.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
        Background="Transparent"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="581" d:DesignWidth="733" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Border BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="12" Padding="0.5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>

            <Image Height="543" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="711" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Login.jpg" ImageFailed="image1_ImageFailed" />

            <TextBox Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,177,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="0" Text="Please enter your email address." FontSize="18" Foreground="White" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
            <TextBox Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,256,0,0" Name="textBox2" Text="Please enter your password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299" />
        </Grid>


    </Border>
</Window>
```

Is it possible to overlap a border on a grid?

You can see what I mean from this screen dump:

[image: Corner]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED XAML for clarity and some more comments:**

The `Grid` is being bordered correctly with rounded corners. What should really be the question here is:

> **Is it possible to overlap a Grid Border on the elements contained in the Grid?**

AFAIK, it's not possible. If you want everything contained in the `Grid` to be clipped to the corner radius of the `Border`, you'll need to apply a `Clip` to the `Grid` so that any contained elements don't overlap the border.

```
    <Image 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="10" 
        Name="image2" 
        Stretch="None" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Source="/test;component/login_btn.jpg"> <!-- Make sure it's not
                                                     a self closing tag
                                                     ending in "/>" -->
        <Image.Clip>  <!-- Image.Clip needs to be enclosed between
                           the Image opening tag (above) and
                           the Image closing tag (2 lines below). -->
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="18" RadiusY="18" Rect="0,0,103,30" />
        </Image.Clip>
    </Image>  <!-- Close the Image tag here. -->
```

The clipping area for the image is defined as a `RectangleGeometry` with rounded corners. You can adjust the attributes to match your button image.

Here's a screenshot of my test with one image left as is, and the other clipped to the geometry:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the error the attachable property "Clip" was not found in type "image"

Comment: @Garrith Check my edit. Ensure that you have placed the Clip tag in the right place.

Comment: @down voter: It would be nice to know why my answer was down-voted. Even a short comment would be helpful.

Comment: Torrential that was brilliant for some reason that worked not sure why my clip tag wasnt working but im guessing it was the end close /> like you mentioned in your answer. Initially I thought it wasnt working but height and width dont directly imply the dimension ratios on the tooltip display of the image. But I finally got it all working.

Answer (score 1):

No it wont work as your image is a jpg and the background is a fixed colour, try GIMP if you cant get or use PS to remove corners and save as a PNG. The background will then be transparent.